# How to add scrolling to uiviewcontroller?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, scroll

Good day!
I have view controller in storyboard, its height more than default size and it is not scrolling. how to make it so? i tried to add uiscrollview to uiview but it didn't help. thanks for answering=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution: for correct working scrolling you need ONLY add constraint horizontal and vertical spaces + spaces from top and bottom Layout guide=) stay on scroll view - touch button "Add missing constraints"... after this constraints will be added automatically...=) setting contentSize or frame is not necessary! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` is exactly what you need, however scrolling will only be possible if the `contentSize` of the scroll view is larger than the bounds of the scroll view itself. Try setting the contentSize of the scroll view either in storyboard or pragmatically.

Comment: thanks for answering Patric=) i set it in storyboard to size of uiview but it did not help...